# Match everything except given string

Tags: php, regex

Ok, it's 2 hours that i try. It's time to ask someones here at stackoverflow.

I have this source html:

```
<div class="post_main">
Post Content (has HTML)
</div><div class="post_email">[...]
Other Stuff
<div class="post_main">
Post Content (has HTML)
</div><div class="post_email">[...]
Other Stuff
<div class="post_main">
Post Content (has HTML)
</div><div class="post_email">[...]
```

And so on.
I want to add "Something" before every Post Content.

To do so i'm using preg_replace, but it won't work. Since that i'm actually using

```
'|<div class="post_main">(.*)</div><div class="post_email">|s
```

As regex, the

```
"</div><div class="post_email">"
```

is eaten from the (.*) and i have only one substitution instead of 3.

Now, how can i get this preg match:

Match everthing included newline, but exclude a given string (in this case:

```
"</div><div class="post_email">")
```

?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addSomething($str,$add) {
  $find = '/(<div class=\"post_main\">)/';
  $replace = '$1' . $add;
  return preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from mistabell is complitely appropriate for your case.
If you still want to do it your way - just add one little '?' after the '*' sign.
I mean like this:

```
'|<div class="post_main">(.*?)</div><div class="post_email">|s
```

It calls *lazy quantifier*, and it makes your regexp less greedy.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i just had a similar problem and i fixed it with that amazing "?" ;)